# Meta tags explained: http-equiv and charset

Tags: html

Which is best? And what is the difference?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

or

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Another thing, I see that Viewport meta tags and meta http-equiv tags do not get the /> closing tags as charset and other meta tags have...why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second one is better, since it's more concise. It was standardized that way in HTML5.

As for the tags ending in `/>`: It makes no difference what tag it is. No tag has to close like that in HTML5. In the olden days of XHTML, *all* these tags had to close like that, since XHTML is related to XML.

So, the takeaway is thus:

1. Use an HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>` - Isn't that just nice and simple?
2. Definitely use `<meta charset="utf-8">` - More concise, more betterererererer...
3. No need to close your tags with `/>`

Comment: thank you for your answer. The thing is, not all browsers support HTML 5 right(the older ones now...), so adding the /> is better to accommodate them right?

Comment: @DextrousDave - The HTML5 specification is built in a backwards compatible way (paving the cowpaths), so that it works in all the old browsers still in use (including IE6 - if you consider that "still in use"). So no worries; just use the HTML stuff outlined above, and you'll be alright.

Comment: one more thing,is there a way I can test whether the tags specified in my question is picked up by the browser? I would just like to see a visible difference when those tags are not read (let's say because I made a typo, or forgot to include it...)

Comment: @DextrousDave - You can check your browser's developer tools. If your tags are present, then the browser picked them up correctly....

Answer (score 0):

Reference  : http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_meta.asp

HTML 4.01: meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
HTML5: meta charset="UTF-8"

so the 2nd one is small(html5) and latest

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools. [They're not an authorative source](http://w3fools.com/).